# How to show a button only on hover?

Tags: html, css, angular

I tried many ways but it's not working. I just need a simple button that is visible only on hover.

I have this:

```
<div class = "input-edit"> 
 <button type = "button" class = "edit-button">
     <mat-icon class = "material-icons"> edit </mat-icon>
 </button>
```

Edit:
SOLUTION:

```
.input-edit{opacity: 0} .input-edit:hover{opacity: 1 }
```

Comment: `.input-edit{opacity: 0} .input-edit:hover{opacity: 1 }` Try this

Comment: If the element isn't displayed (`display: none`), how would you ever be able to hover over it?

Comment: Thanks Prakah, it's working. Sorry David you are right.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is the way to go and as Prakash suggested, that could be one nice approach, use opacity and you can even use a transition to make the effect smooth

```css
.input-edit {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.input-edit:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `display: none;` property would not work because otherwise the button would not exist. In this case you can give the button an `opacity: 0;` and for hovering an `opacity: 1;`.

Here's the code:

```css
.input-edit {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s; /* Use a transition if you want */
}

.input-edit:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class = "input-edit"> 
 <button type = "button" class = "edit-button">
     <mat-icon class = "material-icons"> edit </mat-icon>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: none;` property

```css
.edit-button{
   display: none;
}
.input-edit {
  min-height:50px;
}
.input-edit:hover .edit-button{
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class = "input-edit"> 
  <button type = "button" class = "edit-button">
     <mat-icon class = "material-icons"> edit </mat-icon>
  </button>  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hide {
   display: none;
   }
    
   .myDIV:hover + .hide {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    }
```

```html
 <div class = "myDIV">Edit</div>
   <button type = "button" class = "edit-button hide">
   <mat-icon class = "material-icons"> edit </mat-icon>
   </button>
```